# Scrolling a ListView CollectionViewSource to a group of items based on a search textbox's text in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on a Windows Phone 8.1 app in XAML and C#.

I have a listview, whose item source is set to a `CollectionViewSource` called `MusicSource`. On the backend in C#, I have an `ObservableCollection` called `source` and the following code populates it by getting getting all the music files on the phone, groups it by artist and then puts them in the CollectionViewSource, which shows them in the listview:

```
var folders = await folder.GetFoldersAsync();
    if (folders != null)
        foreach (var fol in folders)
            await getMusic(fol);

var files = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
foreach (var file in files)
{
    MusicProperties musicProperties = await file.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
    this.source.Add(new Music((musicProperties.Artist.Length > 0) ? musicProperties.Artist : "Custom", (musicProperties.Title.Length > 0) ? musicProperties.Title : file.Name, (musicProperties.Album.Length > 0) ? musicProperties.Album : "Custom Album", file.Path));
}
itemSource = AlphaKeyGroup<Music>.CreateGroups(source, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, s => s.Artist, true);
this.MusicSource.Source = itemSource;
```

The following is the XAML side of it:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="GroupTemplate">
        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                <TextBlock x:Name="SongTitle" Text="{Binding Title}"
                           Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="ArtistName" Text="{Binding Album}"
                           Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemContentTextBlockStyle}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="MusicSource" IsSourceGrouped="true" />

    <DataTemplate x:Key="headerTemplate">
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=contentList}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <SemanticZoom>
        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
            <ListView
                x:Name="contentList"
                SelectionMode="Multiple"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MusicSource}}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GroupTemplate}">
                <ListView.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="True" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource headerTemplate}"/>
                </ListView.GroupStyle>
            </ListView>
        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
    </SemanticZoom>
    <Border
        x:Name="SearchBorder"
        Background="White">
        <TextBox
                x:Name="Search" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

So I get something like the following in the listview:

Michael Jackson

- Bad
- Dangerous
- Thriller

Eminem

- Not Afraid
- The Monster

I have a textbox with the name `search` that is intended to search the listview.

What should happen is that as I type in the textbox, the listview scrolls to the nearest group whose group header matches the text in the textbox. So if I type "Em", the listview should immediately scroll downwards to the "Eminem" category of items.

How would I achieve this?

Also, is it possible to do the same thing, except scroll to the item whose `songTitle` attribute matches that of the text in the textbox?

Answer (score 1):

Wow that is one hard problem.  I've done something very similar in the past.  Basically you want an AJAX solution to an ObservableCollection set.  You can achieve this by writing a search function through your AlphaKeyGroup with the help from a Regular Expression match.  This should return your element that it needs to scroll to.

As for getting to it to search each text change you need to attach a TextChanged Event to the textbox like so:

```
<TextBox x:Name="my_search" TextChanged="my_search_TextChanged" Grid.Row="0" />
```

When it finds a match, you want to scroll to that element with

```
contentList.ScrollIntoView(matching_element);
```

---

Okay, posted the Windows Phone 8.1 Solution : [**ListView Searching Project**](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9F2F16D176D29EFC!5264&authkey=!AFvhCFjR4A4-pPM&ithint=folder%2C)

Highlights included the Searching Routine that are added to the GroupKey class.

```
public T FindMatch(string pattern, GetKeyDelegate getKey)
{
    Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    foreach (T item in this.Items)
    {
        string key = getKey(item);
        Match match = rgx.Match(key);
        if (match.Success)
            return item;
    }

    return default(T);
}
```

---

[image: Screen Shot of Searching For What what]

Comment: Not sure why, but when I integrate your code with what I have, I get the following error as soon as I type in the textbox, `Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable'2[System.Linq.IGrouping'2[System.String,Beta.Music],System.String]' to type`

Comment: hmm, I would need to see how your AlphaKeyGroup is created and does it differ from GroupKeyList<T> that is in my project.  I'm assuming you got the grouping code from a MSDN article as well?

Comment: Yes. I got it from the MSDN article.

Comment: :), then I would check to my model vs. your model and make sure everything lines up.  Unfortunately, you must have everything perfect for this to work especially when we're doing stuff like Template and passing Delegate functions.

Answer (score 0):

Set `ICollectionView.Filter` callback to filter your listview everytime the `TextChanged` event is raised like so:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEven)
    {
        ICollectionView view = lvTest.ItemsSource as ICollectionView;
        string txtToSearch = searchTextBox.Text;
        view.Filter = (p) => { return ((Music)p).ArtistName.Contains(txtToSearch); };
        view.Refresh();
    }
```

That way you avoid having to decide where to set the current item when it matches more than one Artist name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I get a `'Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.ICollectionView' does not contain a definition for 'Filter' and no extension method 'Filter' accepting a first argument of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.ICollectionView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` error for both `Filter` as well as `Refresh()`.

Comment: I was using System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView which i suppose is different for windows phones. In case you are interested i found a tutorial on how to extend the ICollectionview to allow filtering: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/527686/A-WinRT-CollectionView-class-with-Filtering-and-So

Comment: I used the `ICollectionViewEx` class in the link you gave and as I began to type in the textbox, I got the following error: `Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` at the `view.Filter` line.