# Grouped Listview windows-phone

Tags: c#, listview, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, semantic-zoom

I'm trying to to show a grouped Listview based on this class

```
private class EInfo
{
    public double JD { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public string MoreDetails { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
}

private List<EInfo> MEphemeries = new List<EInfo>();
```

This is how I grouped and ordered all the elements in every group:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, EInfo>> query = MEphemeries.GroupBy(pet => pet.Details);

foreach (var group in query)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Group {0}", group.Key);
    group.OrderBy(a => a.JD);
    foreach (var user in group)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("  {0}", user.Date);
    }
}

listviewME.ItemsSource = query;
```

And here goes the XAML:

```
<SemanticZoom Grid.Row="1" Background="Black" x:Name="semanticZoom" >
    <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
        <ListView x:Name="listviewME" IncrementalLoadingThreshold="15">
            <!--<ListView.SemanticZoomOwner>
                <SemanticZoom/>
            </ListView.SemanticZoomOwner>-->
            <ListView.Header>
                <!-- table header-->
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="listviewMEHeader0" Width="140"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="listviewMEHeader1" Width="60"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="listviewMEHeader2" Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="{StaticResource MediumGreyThemeColor}" Margin="0, 0.5, 0, 0.5">                                                  
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Background="{StaticResource MediumGreyThemeColor}" Margin="0, 0.5, 0, 0.5">                                                  
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="2" Background="{StaticResource MediumGreyThemeColor}" Margin="0, 0.5, 0, 0.5">                                                   
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ListView.Header>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="Black" Margin="0,0,0,0">

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="140"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="{StaticResource DarkGreyThemeColor}" Margin="0, 0, 0, 0.5">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource FlyoutPickerTitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Time}" Margin="5,0,5,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" FontSize="14" Foreground="{StaticResource LightGreyThemeColor}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Background="{StaticResource DarkGreyThemeColor}" Margin="0, 0, 0, 0.5">
                            <!--<Rectangle Height="25" Width="25" Margin="0" Fill="{StaticResource MoonThemeColor}" RadiusX="12.5" RadiusY="12.5" />
                            <Rectangle Height="35" Width="35" Margin="0" Stroke="{Binding Color}" StrokeThickness="2" RadiusX="17.5" RadiusY="17.75" />-->
                            <Image Height="30" Width="30" Margin="0" Source="{Binding Icon}" Stretch="Uniform" />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="2" Background="{StaticResource DarkGreyThemeColor}" Margin="0, 0, 0, 0.5" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=listviewMEHeader2}">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Details}" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource FlyoutPickerTitleTextBlockStyle}" Foreground="{StaticResource VeryLightGreyThemeColor}"/>
                                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding MoreDetails}" Margin="5,0,5,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" FontSize="14" Foreground="{StaticResource LightGreyThemeColor}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="True">
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" MinWidth="400" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Blue" Background="AliceBlue" Margin="0,10,5,0" CornerRadius="1">
                                <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Key}"
                                Margin="10,2,2,5" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                                FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="10" />
                            </Border> 
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
        </ListView>
    </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>

    <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
        <ListView Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding query}" Background="White">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Height="99" Margin="16">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Border Background="{StaticResource MediumDarkGreyThemeColor}"  Width="200" Height="111">
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Group.Key}" Style="{ThemeResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" />                                
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>
    </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>

</SemanticZoom>
```

The question is that all the info is grouped Ok, every group with its key, its list of elements correctly ordered by date, but the listview doesn't shows any info. It only some empty blocks (the number of block is the same to the number of groups).

What is the problem? How I can fix this?

This is what I get:

[image: This is what I get]

This is what I want to achieve: 
[image: This is what I want to achieve]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Some stuff I see that might fix your problems:

1) Change your `private class EInfo` to `public`

2) Your first ListView does not have `ItemsSource` set while your second LiewView has it set to `ItemsSource="{Binding query}"`

3) You can group your ListView and GridView nicely by using a `CollectionViewSource` see here : [CollectionViewSource example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31926892/windows-phone-8-1-listview-sticky-header/31932914#31932914)

4) Or you can do it manually by Grouping it into an AlphaKeyGroup, I have a working example here : [AlphaKeyGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25538411/scrolling-a-listview-collectionviewsource-to-a-group-of-items-based-on-a-search/25540720#25540720)

---

Last idea, is to check the output of your GroupBy code vs the CollectionViewSource and AlphaKeyGroup in the debugger to see if they match up.

Comment: To answer your points one by one:
1-. The class is in the same page of the XAML/cs, so this is not a problem. 
2-. I'm having problems in the first listview (actually, there's only one listview, but one is showed when zoomed in and the other when zoomed out -semanticzoom-), 

And it has 'ItemsSource' defined in code. See in the code I posted:
'listviewME.ItemsSource = query;'

For a reason that is unknown for me, if I use 'ItemsSource="{Binding query}"' in XAML doesn't show anything in listview, so I have to do in code.

Comment: For 3rd and 4rd points, I think that my problem is here (this is what I get in debug output window: 

'listviewME.IsGrouping: False

Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Date' property not found on 'System.Linq.Lookup`2+Grouping[[Sy,(...)'

And this binding error for earch of the items I'm trying to show in the listview item list.

It seems like it's trying to get the Date, Time, Icon info from the same level of the 'IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, EInfo>> query = MEphemeries.GroupBy(pet => pet.Details);'

Comment: @ImanolZubiaurre yeah; I would look at the CollectionViewSource example from Microsoft.  If your {Binding query} is not working, then you must have the incorrect DataContext set/binded.  I have done it both ways above and it works perfectly.

Comment: Finally I'd got a good solution from this example: [basic links] http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2014/07/15/phone-listview-grouping
Not the perfect one or the one that I wanted but works ok.